# Javascript Get Selected Text: Incorrect number of lines

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using the following code

```html
(function(e, t) {
    "use strict";
    var n = t.selection;
    var i = t.getSelection;
    var o = i || n;
    var r = function(e) {
        var t = Object.prototype.toString.call(e);
        return typeof e === "object" && /^\[object (HTMLCollection|NodeList|Object)\]$/.test(t) && e.hasOwnProperty("length") && (e.length === 0 || typeof e[0] === "object" && e[0].nodeType > 0)
    };
    var c = function(e, t) {
        var n;
        return function() {
            var i = this,
                o = arguments;
            var r = function() {
                n = null;
                e.apply(i, o)
            };
            clearTimeout(n);
            n = setTimeout(r, t)
        }
    };
    var s = function(t, n) {
        this.element = t;
        this.callback = n || function() {};
        this.isTouch = "ontouchstart" in e;
        this.hasLib = e.jQuery && t instanceof e.jQuery || e.Zepto && t instanceof e.Zepto
    };
    s.prototype = {
        events: function() {
            var e = this.callback;
            var t = this.getText;
            this[this.isTouch ? "bindTouch" : "bindMouseUp"](function() {
                e(t())
            })
        },
        getText: function() {
            var n = "";
            if (i) {
                n = e.getSelection().toString()
            } else if (t.selection && t.selection.type !== "Control") {
                n = t.selection.createRange().text
            }
            return n
        },
        checkForSelections: function(e, t, n) {
            var i;
            var o = function(e) {
                var n = t();
                var i = setInterval(function() {
                    if (t() !== n) {
                        e(t());
                        n = t()
                    } else if (t() === "") {
                        clearInterval(i)
                    }
                }, 100)
            };
            var r = function() {
                e.removeEventListener("touchend", c, false);
                e.addEventListener("touchend", c, false);
                if (i) {
                    clearInterval(i)
                }
                i = setInterval(function() {
                    var e = t();
                    if (e !== "") {
                        n(e);
                        c();
                        o(n)
                    }
                }, 100)
            };
            var c = function() {
                clearInterval(i);
                e.removeEventListener("touchend", c, false)
            };
            e.addEventListener("touchstart", r, false)
        },
        bindTouch: function(e) {
            var t = this.checkForSelections;
            var n = this.getText;
            if (this.hasLib) {
                this.element.each(function() {
                    t(this, n, e)
                });
                return
            }
            var i = function(i) {
                t(i, n, e)
            };
            if (!r(this.element)) {
                i(this.element);
                return
            } [].forEach.call(this.element, function(e) {
                i(e)
            })
        },
        bindMouseUp: function(e) {
            if (this.hasLib) {
                this.element.on("mouseup", c(e, 150));
                return
            }
            var t = function(t) {
                t.addEventListener("mouseup", c(e, 150), false)
            };
            if (!r(this.element)) {
                t(this.element);
                return
            } [].forEach.call(this.element, function(e) {
                t(e)
            })
        }
    };
    e.selecting = function(e, t) {
        if (!o) {
            return
        }
        new s(e, t).events()
    }
})(window, document);
```

And :

```html
    var myElement = document.body;
  
    window.selecting(myElement, function(selector) {
    var text = selector;
      
    instance.publishState("text", text);

});
```

to basically get the selected/highlighted text by the user in the browser. I then use the selected text to work with it, make API calls etc.

Getting the selected text is fine, but unfortunately the number of lines in the returned text is usually incorrect which makes it impossible for me to work with.
Let me give you an example:

The user highlights the following text on the page:

```
Hello this is a test

Hello this is another test
```

The returned value from my code however than displays this text but with more line breaks in between. So for example I get returned:

```
Hello this is a test



Hello this is another test
```

This completely breaks my functionality, as I have to exactly know how many line breaks there actually are in order to work with the text. Any ideas what could be wrong or how I can access the browsers selected text with the correct number of line breaks?

Comment: Could you split the string on each line break to put it into an array, then loop the array and remove any indexes that are null/empty strings. then you will have an array without any empty lines? That is my first thought but I haven't thought very hard about it thus adding a comment and not an answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I formatted it .

Comment: Why are you showing us obfuscated code we cannot check because of a missing [reprex]? When this is 3rd party code, contact the original developer...

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```

will return the correct selection, which will produce in your case

```
Hello this is a test\n\nHello this is another test
```

Notice how you have two `\n` corresponding to the 2 newlines you have.

So if you do anything like this to display what the user has selected:

```
console.dir(window.getSelection().toString());
```

You will see correctly what the user has selected

```
Hello this is a test

Hello this is another test
```

Comment: No I just tried it. it doesn't work...